# Reading xml files in android - Parsing

Tags: android, xml, string, list, xml-parsing

I am new to xml file reading in android. I looked up google for this but could not get an appropriate solution.

I wish to parse this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>aaaa</key>
        <array>
                <string>b</string>
                <string>c</string>
                <string>d</string>
                <string>e</string>
                <string>f</string>
        </array>
        <key>bbbb</key>
        <array>
                <string>g</string>
                <string>h</string>
                <string>i</string>
                <string>j</string>
                <string>k</string>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

After parsing, I wish to obtain the following correspondance:

aaaa    [b,c,d,e,f] -> a list/array

bbbb    [g,h,i,j,k] -> a list/array

In other words, every string(key) should correspond to the array of the strings inside that key.

How do I do it? Also, I would like to know where I should place the xml file. (Is it in the res/raw/ folder ? If yes, then what would be the address of the file?)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html .. a nice tutorial for xml parsing

Comment: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/01/xml-parsing-using-saxparser-with.html is also a goo tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A first draw to do that on your own :

```
public final class XMLManager {


public static HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> getHmPlist(){

    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> hmPlist = null;

    try {


        hmPlist = new HashMap<>();
        Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("D:\\Loic_Workspace\\Test2\\res\\test.xml"));
        NodeList ndList = doc.getElementsByTagName("key");
        Integer keyLength = ndList.getLength();
        String keyValue = null;
        NodeList ndArray = null;
        Integer ndArrayLength = null;
        ArrayList<String> alElement = null;

        for(int i=0;i<keyLength;i++){
            alElement = new ArrayList<>();
            keyValue = ndList.item(i).getTextContent();
            if(keyValue != null){
                ndArray = ndList.item(i).getNextSibling().getNextSibling().getChildNodes();
                ndArrayLength = ndArray.getLength();
                for(int j=0;j<ndArrayLength;j++){

                    if(ndArray.item(j).getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("string")){
                        alElement.add(ndArray.item(j).getFirstChild().getTextContent());
                    }

                }

                hmPlist.put(keyValue, alElement);

            }

        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return hmPlist;

}



}
```

In order to anserw your question regarding res/raw/ folder. Yes you have to put your XML in that folder and used it in your Java code via the R class.

Hope it helps,